# mu4e: Refiling email while making an org-todo

Tags: org-mode, mu4e, org-capture, doom

### Background:

I read my email through mu4e in (Doom) emacs. I set up an org-capture template that stores a TODO with a link to the current email I'm viewing, all working great.

Typically I do this from the inbox email folder, and I like to keep that clean, so I refile emails to my "All email" folder when I'm done with it.

If I refile *after* I added the org-todo, then the contained link no longer works (points to where the email *used* to be).

I'd like to keep my email inbox empty when I already track the todo elsewhere.

### My question:

Is there a way to refile a message in mu4e, and at the same time add an org-todo with a *valid* link to the email?

I imagine I could write a custom elisp function to do it, but I'm not too comfortable with elisp in particular. I don't expect a copy-paste complete solution, but any help or pointers would be much appreciated!

**Config:**

I'm using Doom emacs with very little additional config, with

```lisp
(doom! 
   ;; ...
   ;; lots of unrelated modules
   ;; ...
       
   :email
   (mu4e +gmail))
```

The capture template I have looks as follows:

```lisp
(setq org-capture-templates 
  '(("m" "Mail" entry (file+headline "~/org/gtd.org" "Tasks")
     "* TODO Mail: (%:fromname) %:subject\nSCHEDULED:%t\n:PROPERTIES:\n:CREATED: %U\n:END:\n %a" :immediate-finish t :prepend t))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [manual](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Org_002dmode-links.html), what you store is either a link to a particular message (from message-view) or the last know query to it (from headers view). I guess the latter, the query, is what gives you trouble.

To avoid that, with the minimum fuss you can, either:

- Link from the message view.
- Refile first, then link.

or with a little work, pack everything in your own command skipping capture interface.

---

Although this is what the 1.4.6 manual states, I'm using 1.4.10 and I'm getting the same behavior of linking to the message id no matter from where I capture, and it doesn't get affected by refiles, or so it seems in a quick test.